# Process Monitor > Name Not Found for I/O > Grails Application

Tags: grails, grails-2.3, process-explorer

I'm trying to speedup the startup of a grails 2.3.7 application.
Part of this has been to move stuff over to a RamDrive and start the project and inteli-j from there.

I have noticed though that grails tries to read many files, and in many cases these files are not there or the path is not there.

It seems very hectic and disorganized.

Does anyone have any idea how to improve and avoid these redundant and inefficient system calls as well as how to speedup startup?

Is it a matter of grails itself or the specific plugins being included?

[image]

Picture available at [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv2Re.png) as well.

Additionally, below please find the graphs for the various operations performed during startup. Unfortunately the CPU usage is never up to 100% meaning grails startup may not be optimized to use all cores.

[image]

Comment: You might want to include what version of Grails you are using in your question.

Comment: @Joshua Moore Done, thanks!